# How can I merge directories on separate servers?

Tags: linux, directory, centos, replication, rsync

I have 3 separate servers with a sharded image directory (a0-z9).  Unfortunately my rsync and php upload script broke along the way and now I have 3 unmatched directories on 3 servers that are supposed to be identical.  I'm not concerned with overwriting... if it's already there, there's no need to overwrite it — it's the same.

ServerA

```
/path/img/a0/001/
/path/img/a0/.../
/path/img/a0/999/
/path/img/../
/path/img/z9/001/
/path/img/z9/.../
/path/img/z9/999/
```

ServerB and ServerC have the same layout.  All have the exact same 2-digit directory structure (260 directories, a0-z9).  But they have different sub-directories.  ServerA may have `a0/001/`, but this directory might be missing on servers B & C (or the other way around).

I need to merge all 3 directories.

Ultimately if `c7/003/` exists on one server, it needs to exist on all 3.

How can I do this?  I've already fixed it going forward, but I still need to clean up the current mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rsync command for syncing two folders (given a good source and an outdated/broken destination) is provided below, your script dies probably because it runs too long. Try running it for smaller subdirectories.

```
rsync -a --delete-after /source/images/ -e 'ssh -l username' \
    hostname:/path/to/destination/images/
```

Comment: Thanks.  Though I'm not sure "--delete-after" is what I'm after.

Comment: --delete-after works on the destination and removes what is not found in the source. It _is_ what you are after if you are looking to clean things up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Unison, since you want two-way synchronization. First synchronize Server 1 with Server 2, then server 1 with server 3 and, finally, Server 1 again with server 2. In the end, all three servers should have the same set of files.